# How to show $15 \mid 2^{4n}-1$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For all $n \ge 1$ use mathematical induction to establish the divisibility of the statement: 
>   $$
> 15 \mid 2^{4n}-1
> $$

So first i substituted $1$ in and proved the statement to be true by example 
then for my assumption I put $k$ in for $n$ and for my proof so far I have:

\begin{align*}
15 &\mid 2^{4(k+1)}-1 \\
RHS & =2^{4k+4} -1 \\
&=2^4 \cdot 2^{4k}-1
\end{align*}

Is the splitting in the last step correct? Also how do I/where do I substitute my induction hypothesis into the equation? step by step explanation please!

Comment: The proof is a very slight variation of that for your essentially duplicate [prior question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/669106/242) asking if it is divisible by $5$.

Comment: I've updated your question title to be more descriptive.  Please use descriptive titles in the future.  Regards

Answer (score 4):

Your work is good so far.  Now notice that

$$
2^4 \cdot 2^{4k}-1 = 16 \cdot 2^{4k} - 1 = (2^{4k} - 1) + 15 (2^{4k})
$$

Your induction hypothesis is that $15 \mid 2^{4k }- 1$.  Also, it is true that $15 \mid 15(2^{4k})$.  So what do you know about the sum?

Comment: @Lil $2^4 = 16$.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to you an alternative proof. Note that $$2^{4n}-1=16^n-1$$

And $p(x)=x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$ by evaluating at $x=1$ for $p(1)=0$.

Comment: But, as written, that's not a proof *by induction* (as requested).

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, I knew many people would address that already, so I shared an alternative solution the OP might find useful.

Comment: When you do that it is  always a good idea to *explicitly*  say so at the start, since otherwise readers might be confused, wondering how it is an inductive proof (esp. readers new to induction).

Answer (score 0):

The statement is

$$
P(n):\quad 15 \mid 2^{4n} - 1.
$$
You have proved that $P(1)$ is true. Now you need to prove that if $P(k)$ is true then $P(k+1)$ is true. So you may assume that 
$$
15 \mid 2^{4k} -1.
$$
to prove that 
$$
15 \mid 2^{4(k+1)} -1
$$
is true.
But if you unpack this a bit
$$\begin{align}
2^{4k + 4} - 1 &= 2^4\cdot2^{4k} -1 \\&= 16\cdot 2^{4k} - 1 \\&= (15 + 1)\cdot 2^{4k} - 1\\ &= 15\cdot2^{4k} + 1\cdot 2^{4k} - 1 \\&=15\cdot2^{4k} + (2^{4k} - 1)
\end{align}
$$
and both of these terms are divisible by $15$ (using your hypothesis). That is, assuming that $P(k)$ is true, you have proved that $P(k+1)$ is true.

Comment: how do you go from this step:(15+1)⋅24k−1 to this step =15⋅24k+24k−1?

Comment: @Lil: I distribute the $2^{4k}$ over the sum $15 + 1$. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok makes sense. last question-how do you know that the final statement: 15⋅24k+(24k−1) is divisible by 15?

Comment: @Lil: Because each of the two terms: $15\cdot2^{2k}$ and $2^{4k} - 1$ are divisible by $15$. And the sum of two terms that are both divisible by $15$ is again divisible by $15$ (like in Goos' answer).

Comment: how is (2^4k)-1 divisible by 15?

Comment: @Lil: That is exactly the induction hypotheses. You have that because you are assuming that $P(k)$ is true.

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Comment: @Lil: No problem. Glad to help.